# Manipulate ::selection pseudo-element in developer tools

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, firefox-developer-tools, ie-developer-tools

Is it possible to adjust the properties of the :selection pseudo-element in Developer Tools?

I'd like to be able to test different background and font colors for selections without modifying the source CSS file, but I cannot find the pseudo-element anywhere when inspecting the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this in Internet Explorer and Firefox by right-clicking inside the *Styles* panel and selecting *New Rule*.

1. Right-click in **Styles** panel
2. Select *Add New Rule* from context menu
3. Write new `::selection` rule and add properties

[image]

Chrome has a small icon in the *Styles* panel that you can click to create a new Rule.

1. Click *New Style Rule* button in **Styles** panel
2. Write new `::selection` rule and add properties

[image]

Comment: Cool! Thanks for that. However, this only seems to work (in Chrome, at least) if there isn't an existing `::selection` rule in the stylesheet.

Comment: @Mute You can give your selection rule higher specificity. Apply it directly to the element you wish `p::selection`, or set `!important` after the value for testing purposes.

Comment: Right on. `!important` will work well in this instance.

Answer (score 4):

The `::selection` pseudo element is available in Chrome's dev tools as the last style in the styles pane - almost as if it were the least specific style. To view it, make sure you have it defined in your stylesheet, then select some text and inspect one of the selected words/areas.

[image: Inspecting the ::selection pseudo element in Chrome's Dev Tools]

As was mentioned by @Sampson, you can also add `::selection` styles using just `::selection` or a more specific selector, like `p::selection` or `span::selection`. Keep in mind, however, that according to the spec, you can only affect the `color`, `background-color`, `cursor`, `outline`, `text-decoration`, `text-emphasis-color` and `text-shadow` with the `::selection` pseudo element.

Another consideration when using the `::selection` pseudo is that you may be affecting accessibility by creating selections that lack in contrast. You also may be affecting visibility of links. In such cases, you can test your contrast using a contrast examiner tool and you can create more specific `::selection` styles for links - something like:

```css
span::selection {
    background-color: #b3d8fd;
}

a.footnote span::selection {
    color: #920000;
}
```